# Access to the path denied Amazon s3 getObject method .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I am developing a console application to download a file from an S3 bucket with the following code snippet:

```
using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
     GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
     {
          BucketName = bucketName,
          Key = keyName
     };

     using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
     {
          string dest = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, keyName);
          if (!File.Exists(dest))
          {
               response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.HttpStatusCode);
          }

      }
 }
```

the workingDirectory variable is:

```
string workingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\rawfiles";
```

and i got the ***Access to the path is denied error*** this is the following stack trace

'System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFile(String filePath, Boolean append)
   at Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFile(String filePath)
   at AmazonObject.classes.DownloadS3Object_class.GetObject(String bucketName, String keyName, String workingDirectory) in c:\Users\user1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Web Projects\myr_cron\myr_cron\DownloadS3Object_class.cs:line 45

line 45 is this:

```
response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
```

how do I solve this?